# AIX 5.3 KSH shell control c and continue

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh, aix

I have the following simple code in AIX 5.3 and I want to continue to run the next command after control c command.

```
#!/bin/ksh

stty intr ^c
##trap "" 2
 clear
 trap  2
##stty intr '^C'

ls /tmp|more
 echo "Press <Enter> To continue.\c"
 echo ""
 read
exec

echo "you are exiting................................."
sleep 2
exit
```

I would like to get the following output without going to command prompt again after control C command. Pl. help me to get the required output.

```
[root@rss1 tmp]# su - testuser
ch.log
ch_UPDTST.log
cust
cust.unl

Press <Enter> To continue.\c

[root@rss1 tmp]#
```

Thanks !
Best Regards,
Indika

Comment: `su - testuser` is not the right command to execute a shell-script. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks .We agree with you. Pl. consider this is test server and if you execute as test user you will get the same issue.

Comment: It is totally unclear what do you wish to achieve. Maybe you wish to ignore Ctrl+C. Or you wish to leave `more` when you press Ctrl+C. Or something entirely different.